# How to create custom taskbar tumbnail in Win7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, pinvoke

How do I use DwmSetIconicThumbnail in c# to set an applications taskbar tumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). I wouldn't recommend trying to P/invoke this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the managed wrapper libraries for dwm in C#, or use it by yourself using C# interop

Comment: Which namespace can I find the DWM wrapper? What reference do I need to add? At what point do I set iconic tumbnail, onload/initialize? Any code sample you can point me to? Thanks